# Font Awesome Icon with characters on it

Tags: css, font-awesome

I would like to have font awesome with charaters on it , but it fails to do that.Please help to understand whats going on wrong.

**Output :**

[image]

**Code Tried :**

```
<i class="fa fa-square fa-2x" style="color:red;"><span style="text-color:white;">S</span></i>
<i class="fa fa-square fa-2x" style="color:yellow;"><span style="text-color:white;">XL</span></i>                                           
<i class="fa fa-square fa-2x" style="color:green;"><span style="text-color:white;">XXL</span></i>
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be really helpful

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want the letters to be completely inside the coloured squares? If so, don't use font-awesome, just style them as span tags, and use CSS.

Comment: @TasosK. thanks for reply.there are no code other than this so just pasted code.

Comment: @Lee thanks for reply. yes you are correct,Can't I achieve that in font-awesome.?

Comment: For anyone interested, here's a fiddle of the OP's markup with the Font Awesome libraries... Might come in handy for other testing down the road too: http://jsfiddle.net/nkxbx9d2/

Comment: Can you explain why you're doing that? is it just square or also something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't use Font Awesome, as this will only output icons using CSS content, and you can't put any HTML markup 'inside' them.

The best thing would just be to use span tags, and style them using CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/7uevq7pu/

HTML:

```
<span class="red">XL</span>
<span class="yellow">S</span>
<span class="green">XXL</span>
```

CSS:

```
span { border-radius:5px;padding:0 5px;text-align:center; }
.red { background:red; }
.yellow {background:yellow; }
.green { background:green; }
```

Comment: @sunleo Also, `text-color` isn't what you want to use. Just `color` will change the font... http://jsfiddle.net/fpaae5ma/

Comment: Oh yeah, that's weird why I typed that!

Comment: Although I didn't use text colour as white, as it makes the yellow impossible to read. Better to use a darker colour.

Comment: @sunleo I hope my answer, answered your question! Did you manage to solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

You can also define content as icon:

http://jsfiddle.net/tagliala/77re29ct/24/

```
.fa-a:before {
   font-family: Arial; /* your font family here! */
   font-weight: bold;
   content: 'A';
}
<span class="fa fa-a"></span><br/>
```